# Finding if HasMany Through relationship exists - CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a HasMany Through relationship between User and Item. The problem is - I want to check if the relationship exists (meaning find exactly user_id and item_id on same row) to check if the action taken was to add or remove that relationship.

The problem seems to be in this line of code that always evaluates to more than 0 no matter what user I'm logged in as - while it should find nothing if i'm logged under a user with no upvotes:

```
$something = $this->Upvote->find('count', array('Upvote.item_id' => $this->request->data['item_id'], 'Upvote.user_id' =>  AuthComponent::user('id')));
```

Basically all I want to do is find if a HasMany Through relationship exists between the logged in user, and each item. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$something = $this->Upvote->find('count', 
       array( 'conditions'=> 
               array('Upvote.item_id' => $this->request->data['item_id'],
                    'Upvote.user_id' =>  AuthComponent::user('id')
               )
     )
);
```

Comment: Thanks - the issue is that it's an index - so I need to find for each Item if the relationship exists with the user. How do i do that? I tried a foreach on the set() and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The code of u2460470 is correct. You need to loop between the Items:

```
foreach ($items as $item){ 
 $upvotes = $this->request->find('count',array('conditions'=>
      array('Upvote.item_id' => $item,
                'Upvote.user_id' =>  AuthComponent::user('id')               
   )));}
```